# Can a response to an Apollo mutation omit fields?

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

Right now, after a successful mutation I send another request for the updated data. I'd like to eliminate this second request.

According to the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/watching-queries/#controlling-normalization), if I implement object IDs I can get cache updates for free. This relies on the graphql server returning a response (with the updated data) that can be normalized by Apollo.

Can the mutation response only include **some** of the fields for my object? For example I have a `Hero` object that defines a Hero's `name` and `age`. But the UI only allows the user to change the name. Can I return just the Hero's `name` in the response to leave the `age` untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can query any field you want from the result of `mutation` in the same way as for `query`. You just have to return your object after updating it.

For example:

```
mutation {
  updateHero(newHero: { name: "John Doe" }) {
    name
  }
}
```

One more thing. Although it is recommended to return the updated object from the `mutation`, on the other side, it is also recommended to design your GraphQL server as per your UI needs. So if you think you won't need the whole object after updating, you can always return only name.

In this schema your schema will look like the following:

```
Mutation {
  updateHero(newHero: UpdateHeroInput!): String!
}
```

And the corresponding query will be:

```
mutation {
  updateHero(newHero: { name: "John Doe" })
}
```

Note, there's no selection of fields as it returns a single scalar value (String).

Comment: Great answer, but a few caveats: From what I've read your suggestion to use a scalar return value is advised against, see the "Designing the mutation payload" section here: https://blog.apollographql.com/designing-graphql-mutations-e09de826ed97. Also, in my question I said that UI does not allow user to modify the age, so the input to the mutation should not include an `age` argument.

Comment: Hey @GilBirman. For the age, I just added an example. It has nothing to do with the solution I provided. For the scalar value, please read once again the second paragraph of my answer. I mention that it's recommended to return the whole object from at least update mutation. *However*, there's another side of things, which I mentioned. For more details, please check this out: https://principledgraphql.com/agility#5-use-an-agile-approach-to-schema-development

Comment: From your link: "it should be possible to change the graph many times a day if necessary. New fields can be added at any time. To remove a field, it is first deprecated, and then removed when no consumers use it." It's not possible to deprecate/add a field in the response if you are returning a scalar in the response.

Regarding `age`, the answer is less confusing if the hero example is consistent with the hero example in the original question.

Comment: Before that paragraph, it says: "Fields shouldn't be added to the schema speculatively. Ideally, each field should be added only in response to a concrete need by a consumer for additional functionality, while being designed for maximum reuse by other consumers that have similar needs."

And I'm not talking about general case, I'm talking about your specific case. From my answer: "So if you think you won't need the whole object after updating, you can always return only name.".

I'm not sure why that `age` bothers you so much, anyway, will remove it now.